# Java Get All Working Days in a year in YYYYMMDD format

Tags: java, date, time, java-8

My Sunday challenge is to get and persist working days in a particular year to a CSV, etc file.

I have following code and the problem I am facing is : how to print dates in a specific format i.e. YYYYMMDD as the code currently prints something like Sat Jan 19 00:00:00 CET 2019.

Also, if I can exclude week-ends and generally if there is a better way to write a much shorter code in Java 8.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DatesInYear
{

    public static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        Date dt = new Date();
        System.out.println(dt);

        List<Date> dates = printDates("20190101","20191231");


        Collections.reverse(dates);
        System.out.println(dates.size());
        for(Date date:dates)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            System.out.println(format1.format(date));

        }
    }
    public static List<Date> printDates(String fromDate, String toDate)
    {
        ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

        try {

            Calendar fromCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            fromCal.setTime(dateFormat .parse(fromDate));

            Calendar toCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            toCal.setTime(dateFormat .parse(toDate));

            while(!fromCal.after(toCal))
            {
                dates.add(fromCal.getTime());
                fromCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return dates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just `System.out.println(date)`, use the `dateFormat` that you already made to format it in the way you need it.

Comment: `String date1 = format1.format(date);` then you do nothing with `date1`. But you are on the right track.

Comment: `Calendar` can also be used to check for day of the week.

Comment: What's your Java version? 8 or 9+?

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the old cumbersome legacy date api instead of `java.time`?

Comment: If you tag your question correctly (added date and time), then the date/time experts will be able to find your question and you will get good responses quicker.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your format is built-in, `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's 2 slightly different takes on your problem:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class DatesInYear {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        listWorkingDays(2020).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<LocalDate> listWorkingDays(final int year) {

        IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1,      LocalDate.ofYearDay(year + 1, 1).minusDays(1).getDayOfYear())
            .mapToObj   (day  -> LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, day))
            .filter     (date -> date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() <= 5)
            .forEach    (System.out::println);

        return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1,      LocalDate.ofYearDay(year + 1, 1).minusDays(1).getDayOfYear())
            .mapToObj   (day  -> LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, day))
            .filter     (date -> date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() <= 5)
            .collect    (Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, this looks really sleek. I am just putting together some unit tests around but looks really interesting. Cheers

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `IntStream` ? It will display the dates twice. Or why don't you leave only the first `IntStream` and change the return type to void ? I'm just curious.

Comment: As I mentioned it's just 2 takes on the problem: one prints, one returns. JavaMan can pick whichever he wants. :-)

Comment: I do not like these new idioms are ineffecient in general , LocalDate.ofYearDay will create a new instance every time  https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#L285 ,  if you put this code in a highly use method, it wont be the most efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's 2020, you really should be embracing the `java.time.*` API.

While I'm sure there's probably a really neat way to get the "working" days between to dates, I've gone for the brute force method...

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate endDate = ld.plusYears(1);

// You don't "have" to put into a list, but I like to seperate my
// code responsbilities ;)
List<LocalDate> workDays = new ArrayList<>(365);
System.out.println(endDate);
while (ld.isBefore(endDate)) {
    // This would be a good place for a delegate to determine if we want the specific day
    // as it could then take into account public holidays
    if (ld.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || ld.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        // NOOP
    } else {
        workDays.add(ld);
    }
    ld = ld.plusDays(1);
}
```

Then you can simply use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `LocalDate` into a format that you want, for example...

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
List<String> formats = workDays.stream().map(value -> value.format(format)).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String value : formats) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: [there is an existed method to iterate in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366269/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene So - it's essentially a shorthanded version of what I've done anyway - nice to know

Comment: sort of, yes, ultimately it does `LongStream.rangeClosed(0, steps).mapToObj(
                n -> this.plusMonths(months * n).plusDays(days * n));`... But regarding your code, that `ArrayList` could have the size of `240` a rough estimate of `360 - 2 * 40`. Further when you have a `if(condition) {NO-OP} else {OP}` is should be changed to `if(!condition){OP}`

Comment: @Eugene The "no OP" is just there because I didn't want to do `plusDay` twice and I'm also trying to avoid a pyramid of doom - schematics. Pre-sizing the array list is just an attempt to increase the performance - sure we could argue the range, but 365 is guaranteed to cover the core basics - I was leaning towards a reusable code solution where the criteria wasn't known in advance

Comment: I see, understandble.

Comment: @Eugene Like the feed back though 

Answer (score 6):

```
    Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
    LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 1)
             .datesUntil(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 31), Period.ofDays(1))
             .filter(x -> !weekend.contains(x.getDayOfWeek()))
             .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

A lucid way to display all **weekdays** in a date range using Java 8 and modern date-time API is as follows:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocalDate> dates = getDates("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31");
        for (LocalDate date : dates) {
            System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.format(date));
        }
    }

    public static List<LocalDate> getDates(String fromDate, String toDate) {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(toDate).plusDays(1);
        long range = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
        return Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1)).limit(range)
                .filter(d -> !(d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20190101
20190102
20190103
20190104
20190107
20190108
...
...
...
20191226
20191227
20191230
20191231
```

Comment: Very nice. Two things I'd change include storing `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate)` in a variable instead of recomputing every time. Also, for Java 9+ code, one can use `.takeWhile(endDate::isAfter)` instead of `limit()`. Also, you can use enum comparison instead of comparing week day names: `!(d -> d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY || d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)`

Comment: Thanks, @ernest_k for the positive feedback. Your comment means a lot to me. I will improve it as you have suggested.

Comment: @ernest_k - I've incorporated your first comment but left the second one to the readers to incorporate themselves because OP has mentioned that he is using Java 8. Also, my understanding was that JVM would optimise `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate)` instead of recomputing every time. I need your help to understand if it was not correct.

Comment: @ernest_k [or call a method that does the iteration for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366269/1059372)

Comment: Not sure I get the point of doing `d.getDayOfWeek().name().equals("SATURDAY")` when `d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY` which would be more robust - IMHO

Comment: Thanks, @MadProgrammer for the valuable suggestion. I've updated my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Eugene It kinda happens daily that someone mentions something cool I had no idea existed... :-) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LocalDate> dates = getDates("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31");
    for (LocalDate date : dates) {
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.format(date));
    }
}

public static List<LocalDate> getDates(String fromDate, String toDate) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(toDate).plusDays(1);
    long range = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
    return Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1)).limit(range)
            .filter(d -> !(d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Comment: The code is beautiful. You may want to add some explanation of why and how it accomplishes the task.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

// Using Java 8

```
 DateTimeFormatter oldPattern = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter newPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, oldPattern);
    output = datetime.format(newPattern);

    System.out.println("old format date: " + input);
    System.out.println("new format date : " + output);
```

Comment: Nice code, but its relation to the question asked is slipping from me?

Comment: I just given mycode as example here and just he can follow the way i used. but only he needs to take new date format from my code.